# Alternative for ">" in C# on String like in Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

In PowerShell I can compare 2 string :

```
   "002" -gt "001"
```

In C# I can't use ">" with string. So what's alternative ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String.Compare("002", "001", StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

It's best to use one of the overloads that takes [StringComparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter:

> When you call a string comparison method such as String.Compare, String.Equals, or String.IndexOf, you should always call an overload that includes a parameter of type StringComparison so that you can specify the type of comparison that the method performs. For more information, see Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework.